# Android bluetooth audio reroute delay

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth

I use Broadcast listener with `filter` `BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED` to listen for bluetooth changes. When bluetooth is connected I resume playback and when it's disconnected I pause playback.

Problem is that when I receive Bluetooth connected broadcast and I resume playback it plays for 1-2 seconds in phone speakers before audio is rerouted to bluetooth.

```
if (intent.getExtras().getInt(BluetoothHeadset.EXTRA_STATE) == BluetoothHeadset.STATE_CONNECTED){

//these methods doesn't help
mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);

//this returns false
boolean isBluetoothOn = mAudioManager.isBluetoothA2dpOn();

play();
}
```

Only solution I see is to start thread and check periodically if `mAudioManager.isBluetoothA2dpOn()` until it's true and start playback then.

Maybe I am missing something and there is some better solution. Thanks for advice.

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: @GeorgiyChebotarev what I do is I delay playback.resume for some time and only when bluetooth is connected I resume playback.
Code is something like - I have runnable which checks if bluetooth is connected. I put this runnable on handler with 100ms delay. When it runs if bluetooth is connected, it resume playback, if not it will be posted on handler again with same delay.